# Manage utorrent webui with a desktop app

Tags: utorrent

Is there a desktop application that lets you connect to a utorrent server?
It would be nice to manage my torrents away from my browser. Also it would be nice to just open a .torrent file and make it upload the file to the server and start downloading.
I tried to do some google searches but all it displays is how to setup webui...
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with a web interface? It's what I use to manage my BitTorrent client remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW the answer is [uRemote](http://uremote.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question- I use dropbox to add torrents to my torrent box. While this won't let you monitor when a torrent is done, its a fairly seamless way of having torrents downloaded on another box, and it works anywhere.